# Tracking number of code lines added/removed by me

Tags: git, productivity, svn, ubuntu

I do like to write code, but what I like even more is to *remove* code! Following the mantra "code that does not exist cannot have bugs", if we can accomplish the same result with less code, we will make our lives easier in regard to future maintenance (and I've spent a lot of hours in maintenance).

In my new job, I am fortunate enough to be able to do quite a bit of refactoring, and I think that during the first several weeks of my employment, I actually removed more code than I wrote. That got me thinking: I'd like to keep tally.

How can I keep a running balance of lines added and removed across my check-ins in multiple (PHP and Java) projects?

I know about the source code line counter "Ohcount", but that counts the *total* codebase and not just *my* contributions to it. I'm sure it's possible to write a script and stick it into cron, but I'm sorry to say I'm not very good at scripting.

We use both GIT and SVN on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 2):

[SVN Blame](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.blame.html) can output xml, so you can script a blame and aggregate the changes you made in a script. If you combine with the -x flag then it'll only report meaningful changes.

I'm sure [git blame](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame) is much the same, except it has a handy option to show stats.